# MySQL: if field is empty assign a value

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements

Here's my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT u.PHONE , u.STATE , if (uo.CHANNEL='','web',channel) as TYPE FROM user
LEFT JOIN user_oferts uo ON u.PHONE=uo.PHE_USER 
WHERE (u.STATE='active') ";
```

And it is working great, I get what I want BUT for channel that is empty.

I need channel to be "web" if it is not "wap", this way channel will not be empty or null or nothing. How can I do that? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you hav found a valid answer, flag it as accepted so it is not listed as unanswered and also so others might find it easier :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select 
...
case when channel = '' then 
   web 
else 
   channel 
end as TYPE....
```

using the [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case-statement.html) statement.

i.e. for your case

```
$sql = "SELECT u.PHONE , u.STATE 
, case when coalesce(uo.CHANNEL, '') = '' then 'web' else channel end as TYPE 
FROM user
LEFT JOIN user_oferts uo ON u.PHONE=uo.PHE_USER 
WHERE (u.STATE='active') ";
```

**Edit:** added `coalesce` to deal with possible `NULL` values.

Comment: this'll still let a `null` through the net. `case when channel = 'wep' then 'wep' else 'web' end` sounds more like what you're after? what advantage does this have over `if()`?

Comment: Thanks a lot to all, you're amazing!!
It is the case structure what I end up using just because it was easier to get for me, but thanks to all really, you just saved me from more hours of frustration.

Answer (score 3):

Any reason why this can't work?

```
$sql = "SELECT u.PHONE , u.STATE , if (uo.CHANNEL='wap','wap','web') as TYPE FROM user
LEFT JOIN user_oferts uo ON u.PHONE=uo.PHE_USER 
WHERE (u.STATE='active') ";
```

MySQL doesn't like comparing a `null` to a `string`, so you could either nest in another `if` statement testing `uo.CHANNEL IS NULL`, or rather, alter your table so it can't be null, and give it a default value of 'wap'.